# In ASP.NET, is there a way to test membership creation without actually committing the user to the membership database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

I use Membership.CreateUser to create users for my web application on demand.  But is there a way to "test" the value of MembershipCreateStatus for the user without actually writing the user to the membership database?

I know that I can do something like the following:

```
MembershipCreateStatus MCS;
var UN = "user@test.com";
var PW = "password";
var SQ = "What is the answer to this security question?";
var SA = "Security answer";
MembershipUser NU = Membership.CreateUser (UN, PW, SQ, SA, true, out MCS);
```

and then test if MCS is equal to MembershipCreateStatus.Success, MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName, etc.

But this actually ends up creating the user if MCS is equal to MembershipCreateStatus.Success.  Is there a way to test the value of MCS for the combination of UN, PW, etc., without actually creating the user?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For what purpose are you "testing"? e.g. do you need to mock this call for a unit test? Or are you trying to test _this_ call to see if everything except the DB write is working as expected?

Comment: Well, kind of.  I mean, in the worst case I could copy the project, create a new database, point Membership to that database, and then run all my tests, but if it is possible to do some tests without cloning the project, I would prefer that.

Comment: @Shredderroy - You didn't actually answer his question.  WHY do you want to do this?  Chances are, what you want to do either is not a good idea, or there is another way to do it.

Comment: You could just alter the membership configurations in web debug config to make it create an "alternate" application while you have your project in the debug build and when you build for release it'll point to the right one again.

Comment: The reason why I want to do this is because Success is programmed to kick off a chain of consequences which involve writes to several other tables in the database.  Some of these are triggered in the database itself.  I want to have to avoid hunting down all the consequent actions.  That is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest that since you are presumably doing this on a development machine, that you should configure your web.config to point at a development database... Thus, who cares what you dump in there!?

However, if you really don't want to change that... Then you can always go [directly to the database to clean up after yourself](http://www.salmontraining.com/SqlExpressZone/articles/deleting_users_from_membership.html).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll accept this answer.  I don't think there is anything better.